# Not able to Parse json string using SBJsonParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

my Json string is **"{'message':'Test Driver'}"**

if i try to Nslog this code `NSLog(@"%@",[parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil]);`

parser is an object of SBJsonParser class

**Output:** (null)

is there any other json library which can parse this string?

plz help to parse this Json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you van use following code to generate appropriate json string and than parse it. It may help you

```
NSDictionary *resDict = [parser objectWithString:[[request responseString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\""] error:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

The JSON response string is not a valid one, that's the reason why you are getting the error.

Use the following link to check if the JSON string, sent as response from Web services is valid one or not

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 2):

the raw `JSON` string should be in such a format

> {"message":"Test Driver"}

Answer (score 1):

As for other JSON libraries, if you're targeting iOS 5 or newer, Apple provides [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).